# number of training data set and number of model parameters as well as under-fitting, over-fitting

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, overfitting

In practice, there are scenarios such as

Scenario 1: the number of training data is more than the number of model parameters;

Scenario 2: the number of training data is less than the number of model parameters.

Besides, during model training process, there are potential problems such as model under-fitting and model over-fitting.
Are there any relationships between scenario 1, scenario 2 and over-fitting, under-fitting?
Or is there any tendency such as “scenario 1 will always cause over-fitting”?

Comment: It depends on the kind of learning algorithm you're using. If you narrow your question to a particular class of algorithms, you're more likely to get a good answer.

Comment: When I was thinking of this question, I just thought it in a quite generic context. How about asking the question this way? Generally, deep learning has millions of parameters, but in practice we do not have that many data points. Does it mean deep learning is inherently under fitting?

Comment: @user3125 that is probably why [this](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/regularization.html) chapter is prominently placed up front of the latest Deep Learning textbook (Goodfellow et al., 2016): regularization is ubiquitous in deep learning, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does depend on what learning algorithm you're using, as @Dougal notes.  For example, whether you are using regularization like LASSO will change the details of the answer.  Let's assume you are using a cannonical multiple linear regression model without regularization and that the model is (potentially) appropriate in that the conditional distribution of the response really is normal and all relationships between the predictors and the response really are linear.  Then we can say a few things about this:

2. If the number of training data are fewer than the number of parameters, the model is not identifiable.

   If the number of training data is equal to the number of parameters, the model will be just identified.  It will almost certainly be overfit, but it is theoretically possible that it correctly reflects the true data generating process.
3. If the number of training data are more than the number of model parameters, then the model is not necessarily underfit.  It could be underfit, overfit, or have an approximately optimal (given the information available) fit.